# Algorithm for removing chars from string and dynamically resizing it upon removal

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm writing an algorithm to remove all quotation marks from a dynamically sized array and decrease it's length upon removal. Here's my code so far:

```
void remove_quotations(char *str)
{
    int len = strlen(str);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '\'') {
            for (int j = i; j < len - 1; j++) {
                str[j] = str[j + 1];
            }
            len--;
            str = realloc(str, len);
        }
    }
}
```

`Example input: '1357', 'name', 'topic', '2'`

`Expected output: 1357, name, topic, 2`

`What I get: "1357, name, topic, 2''''''''"`

So as you can see the quotation marks get moved to the end as expected, but the string doesn't get shortened like it should.

Note: I'm not doing any error checking on purpose.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Did you run your program in a debugger or do anything else to try and find the problem?

Comment: I did, my expected output is taken from debugging.

Comment: That's testing not debugging. Debugging means stepping thru the code to examine it as it runs. If you have debugged it then you will be able to tell us exactly where/when things start going wrong.

Comment: I did that and there's no change after the `realloc` statement

Comment: Huh? What does "no change" mean? No change from what to what? Could you be any clearer?

Comment: @PoVa you should read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: This algorithm has very poor performance.  Not only is there an N^2 loop-of-loops, there is `realloc()` in the loop!  You should only `realloc()` once, at the end (or perhaps not at all).

Comment: I agree with the `realloc` part, but how can I make it more efficient besides that?

Comment: @PoVa you can replace the inner `for` loop with a `memmove()`

Comment: @PoVa You can improve the efficiency by using linked list. Initially store the characters into nodes of an LL, traverse the LL and alongside delete the node with `'` in it (note deletion takes only `O(1)` time here). And finally form a character array from the LL. Overall complexity `O(n)`. Though unrelated but answers one of your questions in the comments.

Comment: @JohnZwinck the `realloc` is not only inefficient, it is wrong. `str` is a local copy of the calling pointer, so changing it's value does not change the value of the original pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So as you can see the quotation marks get moved to the end as expected, but the string doesn't get shortened like it should.

Well, what *gets* shortened is the area allocated to hold your string, that's what `realloc()` does. You forget to shorten the actual string: A *string* always has a `\0` byte at the end.

Therefore, your program causes *undefined behavior* when you e.g. output this string using `printf()` or `puts()` -- those functions will read until they find the `\0` terminator, and it's not within the region you can legally access after your `realloc()`.

The fact that this seems to work is purely accidental: `realloc()` doesn't give you a new address and the old contents are still there.

There's another error in your code: In case `realloc()` gives you a different address, it will not work, because there's no way for the calling code to take the pointer back.

Side notes:

- when using `realloc()`, assign the result to a temporary variable. In case you get NULL back, you have to `free()` your original variable.
- You only need *one* call to `realloc()` after your loop.

---

For reference, a fixed and commented version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *remove_quotations(char *str)
{
    // always use the correct type, strlen returns size_t:
    // (int would only be a problem here for **huge** strings, still it's better
    //  getting used to ALWAYS use size_t for sizes.)
    size_t len = strlen(str);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] == '\'')
        {
            // move following bytes *including* the final 0 terminator:
            memmove(str+i, str+i+1, len-i);
            --len;
        }
    }

    // include space for 0 terminator when shortening:
    char *tmp = realloc(str, len+1);
    if (!tmp)
    {
        free(str);
        return 0;
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main(void)
{
    char test[] = "'1357', 'name', 'topic', '2'";
    char *foo = malloc(strlen(test)+1);
    strcpy(foo, test);
    foo = remove_quotations(foo);
    if (foo)
    {
        puts(foo);
        free(foo);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This version still uses your original structure of moving the rest of the string on every `'` encountered. That's not overly efficient, see [mch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44824027/2371524) for a much better approach.

---

For completeness, you could just return a *copy* of your original string with something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *remove_quotations(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *dst = malloc(len+1);
    const char *r = str;
    char *w = dst;

    while (*r)
    {
        if (*r == '\'') --len;
        else *w++ = *r;
        ++r;
    }
    *w = 0;

    char *tmp = realloc(dst, len+1);
    if (!tmp)
    {
        free(dst);
        return 0;
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *test = "'1357', 'name', 'topic', '2'";
    char *foo = remove_quotations(test);
    if (foo)
    {
        puts(foo);
        free(foo);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand your version modifies the main string as well (because of the `memmove`). I was looking for a solution that doesn't.

Comment: @PoVa but that's what your original code attempts, doing this *in-place*! A version stripping characters while copying would actually look a bit simpler.

Comment: Sorry, I got things mixed up :D

Answer (score 2):

It is way too complicated what you are doing. You should save the source and destination index and copy each symbol you want to the destination:

```
void remove_quotations(char *str)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (str[i] != '\'') {
            str[j++] = str[i];
        }
    }
    str[j] = 0;
}
```

That is all you have to do.

Working example: http://ideone.com/TU5LOS

Comment: looks good, maybe a bit more explanation and I'd suggest to use `size_t` here as well, who knows how long the string could get ;) Still +1

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use something like this to check the contents of the string:

```
printf("%s\n", str);
```

So, the problem is that `printf` will output all characters it finds in memory until it reaches a terminating `\0` character.

I would update your function like this:

```
char* remove_quotations(char *str)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    char *str_temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '\'') {
            /* go until len so that you shift the '\0' one position to the left */
            for (int j = i; j < len; j++) {
                str[j] = str[j + 1];
            }
            len--;
            /* no need to call realloc here every time */
        }
    }

    str_temp = realloc(str, len + 1);
    if (!str_temp) {
        printf("Memory allocation error!\n");
        free(str);

        return NULL;
    }

    return str_tmp;
}
```

Comment: the `realloc` call is wrong, it invalidates the calling pointer without changing it. It only changes the local copy `str`.

Comment: And the realloc argument should be `len+1`.

Comment: @GUARANG VYAS His loop didn't add the '\0' at the end.

Comment: Yes, @mch is right. I just wanted to point out his main major issue in the function. I will update the `realloc` call to make it correct.

Answer (score 0):

WHen you shift up your string, you have to add `0` at the end of new string:

```
for (int j = i; j < len - 1; j++) {
    str[j] = str[j + 1];
}
str = realloc(str, len);
if (str) {
    str[j] = 0; //String ends with 0, so force 0 at the end of string.
}
```

The point is that you have to manually *close* string by inserting `0` character at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put '\0' at last,

Put below line,

`str[j]='\0';`

before

`len--`